# How should I link related data in a REST API?

Tags: api, rest

I am designing a RESTful API to represent orders and payment transactions. My (simplified) model looks like this:

```
---------     ---------------
| order |----<| transaction |
---------     ---------------
```

i.e. an order can have many transactions. If I have these endpoints to GET the resources:

```
/orders/{id}
/orders/{id}/transactions
```

Where the second call returns a list of transaction objects (expanded or just ids that can be accessed via:)

```
/transactions/{id}
```

Then how should I update the order resource to describe its transactions?

Should I POST a list of transaction object data to `/orders/{id}/transactions` and they will be created and linked to the order resource?

Or should I POST to `/transactions` each transaction and then PUT (or POST?) to `/orders/{id}/transactions` a list of transaction IDs?

...or something else?

What if I already have a transaction resource and want to link it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `POST` to create a transaction for an order, as following:

```
POST /orders/{id}/transactions HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  ... transaction representation ... 
}
```

To link an existing transaction to an order you could consider the *transaction* resource contains a sub-resource called *order*. To replace the order of a transaction, you would use `PUT`, sending the order identifier in the request payload:

```
PUT /transactions/{id}/order HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "order": 100 
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `PATCH` and [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) to partially update the transaction resource:

```
PATCH /transactions/{id} HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/order", "value": 100 }
]
```